# Unity C# Inherited Class Header

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a project with some .cs files I do not want to ever modify as it's being updated by someone else.

So I'm inheriting from the class. In the base class is a header:

```
public partial class BasePlayer : MonoBehaviour {    
    [Header("Stats")]
    [SyncVar] public int stat1 = 0;
    [SyncVar] public int stat2 = 0;
}
```

In my class I want to be able to add in another var to the same header. How would I go about doing this?

```
public partial class MyPlayer : BasePlayer {    
   [SyncVar] public int stat3 = 0;
}
```

And I'm aware it's not very practical to do it this way but I really can't touch the base class.

Answer (score 1):

It's late answer but may help others. Rather than using **Header** attribute; you can use **Serializable** data classes for grouping the stats. For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class GroupOneData
{
    public int stat1;
    public int stat2;
}

[Serializable]
public class GroupTwoData
{
    public int stat3;
    public int stat4;
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T, U> : MonoBehaviour 
    where T : GroupOneData where U : GroupTwoData
{
    public T stats1;
    public U stats2;
}


[Serializable]
public class DerivedOneData : GroupOneData
{
    public int stat3;
}

[Serializable]
public class DerivedTwoData : GroupTwoData
{
    public string text = "yeeyy";
    public float stat3;
}

public class DerviedClass : BaseClass<DerivedOneData, DerivedTwoData>
{
      // You will see all stats in inspector as foldout 
}
```

Some real life examples are (both **GalleryVideoContent** and **GalleryImageContent** are derived from **GalleryContent** class that like BaseClass above):

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution and groupin worked but other issues             

`public class CreatureStats : UnitStats{
    public float metabolism = 1.0f;
}`
`public class UnitStats {
    public float Hitpoints = 100
};`
`public class TLUnit<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : UnitStats {
    public T Stats;
}`
`public class Creature : TLUnit<CreatureStats>{
}`

Now I can no longer make a function that can take a Creature or a TLUnit as an argument e.g. before I would write
`Kill(TLUnit unit)`
Now that doesn't compile. Even if I replace it with `Kill(TLUnit<UnitStats, UnitConfig> unit)`

Comment: @JacobJensen it should be `Kill(TLUnit<T> unit)` or `Kill(TLUnit<T> unit, UnitConfig config)`. If it does not work, please share full code source to findout actual error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the attribute in your class as well like so,

```
public partial class MyPlayer : BasePlayer {    
    [Header("Stats")]
    [SyncVar] public int stat3 = 0;
}
```

> So I'm working on a project with some .cs files I do not want to ever
>   modify as it's being updated by someone else.

Your base class is Partial, You could try the below code.

```
public partial class BasePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
        [SyncVar] public int stat3 = 0;
}
```

The compiler should combine them both into one class.

Here is the output :

[image]

Comment: I tried this before but it just adds a second header in the inspector under the same name.

Comment: @ParallelPancakes I have updated my answer could you try the second way and let me know.

Comment: Changing my inherited class to partial class doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @ParallelPancakes no not your MyPlayer class but create the same class again. BasePlayer like in my second code snippet

Comment: It just creates a second Stats header in the inspector for the new variable.

Comment: @ParallelPancakes could you show me what you are doing? it shouldn't make two.

Comment: @ParallelPancakes I have updated my answer to show you the solution. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little example:

```
public class BasePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    [Header("Stats")]
    public int stat1 = 0;
    public int stat2 = 0;
}

public class MyPlayer : BasePlayer {
    public int stat3 = 0;
    public string duck = "quak";

    [Header("Stats2")]
    public string cow = "mooooo";
}
```

[image: unity example]

Hope to got you right! As far as is understand you this is what you want. If not feel free to give us a little more information like a UnityEditor screen of what exactly you want to see.

PS: When using [SyncVar] your baseplayer should inherit from NetworkBehaviour, right?

Comment: There is additional code in the BasePlayer.cs so when I declare new variables in MyPlayer.cs it isn't under the same "Stats" header. Code-wise it's all fine, but I just wanted to organize the additional variables in the same header as stat1 & stat2.